# I am trying to creating a login system with C programming language

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a login system with the C programming language. the following code below is my attempt, can anyone point out to me  my mistake. 
the Goal is to match the username and password in the program . for example if I were to enter  Amy as username and Amy76 as password is supposed to accept it and print login.

```
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{

    login_session();
    return 0;
}

// following function accepts the login creed for teachers
void login_session(char username[10], char password[10]){
    printf("Enter instructor's Full Name :\n");
    scanf("%s", &username);
    printf("Enter password :\n");
    scanf("%s", &password);

    clrscr();

    //conditional statements to test teachers username and password

    if(strcmp(username, "Amy") ==0) {

        if(strcmp(password,"Amy76") ==0){
            printf("\nwelcome. Login Sucessfully ");
        } else {
            printf("\ninvalid. username and password does not exist");
        }


    } else if (strcmp(username, "Smith") ==0){
        if(strcmp(password,"Smith345") ==0){
            printf("\nwelcome. Login Sucessfully");
        } else {
            printf("\ninvalid.username and password does not exist");
        }
    } else if (strcmp(username, "Doris") ==0) {
        if(strcmp(password,"Doris284") ==0){
            printf("\nwelcome.Login Sucessfully");
        }else {
            printf("\ninvalid. username and password does not exist");
        }
    } else if (strcmp(username,"Wilson") == 0) {
        if(strcmp(password,"Wilson809") ==0){
            printf("\nwelcome.Login Sucessfully");
        }else {
            printf("\ninvalid. username and password does not exist");
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Paul Rooney ,hey thanks i realize my missing parenthesis  and also the fact that I was returning on a void function i corrected that

Comment: You should think about using arrays and/or functions to save writing out so much code repeatedly.

Comment: What *exactly is the problem*?

Answer (score 1):

You can't return 0 to a function which is returning void.

Please mention the **error** you are getting from this code.

Comment: Please use the "add a comment" link to add comments -- the "Add Answer" button should be used for answers to the question, only.

Comment: main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:8:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘login_session’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     login_session();
     ^
main.c: At top level:
main.c:13:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘login_session’
 void login_session(char username[10], char password[10]){
      ^
main.c:8:5: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘login_session’ was here
     login_session();
     ^

Comment: Yeah, there is a mistake in the return type of the function

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, Thanks for the tip. But I knew it already. The thing is that that comment button is not there in mobile version. If it is possible to do so, Please guide me through it.

Comment: @slim, Please tick the answer if it worked out for you. Thanks!

Comment: @ jeremyFriesner , after re reading my code I realize I missed some parenthesis  I added them and the program now compiles but i have a new issue. now that the program runs it does not work . for example entering user name Wilson and the password Wilson809 it returns nothing but this message "Segmentation fault "

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem

after I realized I return 0 to a function which is void  and sort out my parenthesis
I realized i needed a two char array example

instead of this :

```
void login_session(char username[10], char password[10]){    //ect }
```

I tried this:

```
void login_session(){
    char username[10];
    char password[10];
}
```